# Knowledge Management: Is the content of attached files searchable?

Tags: knowledge, search, content, management, sharepoint

Is the content of attached files within knowledge management searchable? If yes, what Kind of document types are supported (doc, xls, pdf,....)?

Second question: is it possible, to connect and include files on SharePoint within search (including searching content of these documents)?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, content of attached files within Knowledge management is searchable.

It supports doc, xls, pdf.

You can include files on SharePoint within search. Refer [Knowledge One with Federated Search](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter14/release-notes/rn_186_knowledge_one_enhancements.htm)